# Error message handling in Infopath 2013

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath2010

We wanted to show the errors/validation messages in Infopath. How can we achieve them as there is no javascript option in infopath.

Comment: You ment custom dialogs?

Comment: yes, so i can notify users for error or validation messages

Comment: check my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136858/how-to-display-a-dialog-box-in-response-to-a-field-value-change-in-an-infopath-f/40419302#40419302